# Will a high interest rate consolidation loan improve my score enough to get a low interest rate loan?

Tags: credit-card, credit-score, interest-rate, personal-loan, debt-restructuring

As documented elsewhere, I'm paying off debt on credit card accounts totalling roughly 15K and at an average interest rate of roughly 20%

My ultimate goal is to get a loan in the 5-8% range with fixed repayment.  I currently only qualify for loans in the 25-30% range.

The question is this:  Will converting my revolving credit to a 30% unsecured personal loan for 2-3 months improve my credit score enough to qualify for a lower interest rate loan?  There are no derogatory marks on my credit report.  Just high utilization and on time payments, but a moderate number of declined application for 0% intro balance transfer cards.

Alternate wording:  Is it feasible to use a high interest rate loan to improve my credit enough to get a low interest rate loan by eliminating credit card debt?

Comment: Trading lower interest loans for higher interest loans is... **backwards** and will cost you more money, thus slowing down your efforts to repay.

Comment: What is the sum of the total lines of credit on the cards? (How much more than 15K is available?) Also, are the current balances lower now since it's been 2.5 months since you asked this question?

Answer (score 6):

If you’re paying on time with no derogatory remarks, I’d guess that your debt to income is just too high to get a better rate.

Don’t give up a lower rate for a higher rate consolidation loan - there is no guarantee you’ll get that even lower rate you’re after. Just keep paying your bills on time.